# scale_y_discrete leads to unequal spacing in y-axis for geom_crossbar

Tags: ggplot2

I have a question here. See code below:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","B","B","C"),low=c(1,2,4,9,1),high=c(2,3,7,12,4))
g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=low,y=id)) + geom_crossbar(aes(xmin=low,xmax=high,y=id), stat="identity",show.legend = NA)
g2 + scale_y_discrete(limits = a$id[order(a$id, decreasing = TRUE)])
```

After using scale_y_discrete with sorting, the spacing in y-axis for id = B is 3 times wide as id = A or C. Is there any option to make them the same spacing for each id?

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few flaws in your code.

- you do not need `y=id` in `geom_crossbar`
- you named the `ggplot` object `g1`, but then refer to `g2`later
- in `scale_y_discrete` you order a **DF** called `a`. It probably should be `df`.

Without changing too much - except correcting things from above - you can reverse the order of y-axis by adding `unique` - see below.

It certainly is helpful to look into good books for **R** and **ggplot** like [R Graphics Cookbook](https://r-graphics.org)

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
  low = c(1, 2, 4, 9, 1), high = c(2, 3, 7, 12, 4)
)
g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = low, y = id)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(xmin = low, xmax = high),
    stat = "identity", show.legend = NA
  )


g1 + scale_y_discrete(limits = unique(df$id[order(df$id, decreasing = T)]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for correction in code and help for solving the issue!

Comment: @`Wansong Xu`  if this solve the problem you may consider accepting this as an answer and / or upvote it